Established Solana Dev for dapp verification
I'm developer of a meme coin on Solana Network.
I've encountered a problem lately concerning my dapp implemented on the website. While confirming the transaction, Phantom Wallet throws warning about my dapp being malicious, so I've contacted blowfish team to solve this. But they've asked me for 'established Solana Dev' to vouch for me that this app is in fact not malicious.
I will be grateful for any help, especially if there's any Solana Dev, that could vouch for me = I will share github files if it's necessary.
